# Calling Controller HttpGet method by actionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I think I read almost all threads about actionLink and HttpGet but I don’t get the routing done.
In my startup class I have the default routing:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
```

I call a website by the controller:

```
public class CollectionController : Controller
    {
public async Task<IActionResult> Collection()
{
    var viewModel = new CollectionViewModel();
    …
    return await Task.Run(() => View("~/Views/Sccm/Collection.cshtml", viewModel));
}
```

And in the View I will call another method in the controller to query more information:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: item.DistinguishedName ?? "Not Found", actionName: "GetCollection", controllerName: "Collection",
                                      routeValues: new { hostname = item.DistinguishedName }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

The method in the same controller looks like that but is never called (breaking point):

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCollection(string hostname)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hostname is: " + hostname);
    return View();
}
```

I noticed that when I change routing in HttpGet I also get linked to another URL, but I never access the function. I assume I am missing some small detail. Any hint would be welcomed.

Thanks

Stephan

Maybe my problem is that the View is in another subfolder then die Controller name

Edit:
Damn it :(, I used the ValidateAntiForgeryToken in a getMethod

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
HttpGet("{hostname}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCollection(string hostname)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hostname is: " + hostname);
    return View();
}
```